# can jQuery.live stop the browser following a link?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use $().live to enhance a website but it insists on following the href. The following is very close to the real code (a.class, span inside a).

```
<a class="test" href="http://google.com"><span>test</span></a>

$('a.test').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('clicked');
});
```

Testing this in [jsfiddle works](http://jsfiddle.net/jakecr/vG5gW/), but not when I use it in my project. The handler is triggered, but the href is also followed.
I've tried both return false and event.preventDefault() with the same result.

Try as I might I can't find anything that would stop this working in my site.

So my question is, should this actually ever work? If so is there anything that would cause it not to?

Comment: @Jake: If it works in the example, doesn't that probably mean there's something else going on with your code?

Comment: Make sure there are no JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thanks @alex, no JS errors. The handler is running too.

Comment: @Jake: Is there any other code before `event.preventDefault()` inside of your handler that could be failing? I saw you don't have any JS errors, but maybe you could just call `event.preventDefault()` inside the handler and see what happens?

Comment: @Andrew, I'm sure you are right, but what could cause this behaviour other than a handler bound earlier that does window.location = `$(this).attr('href');`? I've been through the code many times and can't find anything to cause this. There is a lot of JS, otherwise I'd post it here.

Comment: @andrew, I've just tried this: `$('a.test').live('click', function(e){  e.preventDefault();  console.log('test');  return false;  });` but no luck. Outputs 'test' to the console, then follows href.

Comment: Update: after removing jQuery mobile it works. I'm about to dig in and see what jQmobile is really doing to cause this.

Comment: @Jake: Interesting! Make sure to add an answer and accept it if you figure it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was jQuery mobile. Even with `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false` it captures click events and sets `location.href = $this.attr( "href" );` unless the element has `data-ajax="false"`. I may bind my event before loading jQmobile, or even unbind it's event since I'm not using their nav.

[Offending code in jQuery mobile](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.navigation.js#L713)

Comment: Binding my event before jQmobile loaded doesn't seem to help but `$('a').die('click');` works, feels dirty though.
Thanks for all the answers and comments!

Answer (score 0):

Don't even put the href tag in there you don't need it if you aren't using it as a link.

If you want to control when the link is followed you can remove the href from the link and put window.location in the live() function so you have control when the link is actually followed.

Comment: Sometimes this isn't an option, for example if you're just using JavaScript to enhance your page and you want the links to function normally for people with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: No can do. The hrefs are there as a non-JS fallback.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the jquery code is inside a

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // your code here?

});
```

Here is an updated jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vG5gW/1/

Right now jsFiddle is probably working because the DOM for the link is loaded before the script by luck.

Bob

Comment: Yes. Besides, the handler is running (`$(this).text('clicked');` happens), but it then goes to the href.

Comment: It works in jsFiddle because the code is automatically wrapped in `onLoad()` so you don't need `$.ready` In my real code I use `$.ready`.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are saying, what you COULD do is give the link an id and have jquery replace the value of href. If javascript is not available then the link will remain intact, if not then the link href will be changed to # or whatever you'd like it to.

Comment: Defeats the purpose of using `.live()`. If I was going to do that I'd just use `.click()` with `preventDefault()`